# Errors while running Vuforia samples in Android

Tags: android, vuforia

I am using ADT 23.0.I have installed NDK and set the environment variable.Set variable in class path variables and pointed to vuforia SDK path. Once I deploy the app and choose a sample then click start, It comes back to the previous page.. the camera is not opened.

I got the following errors in my logcat:

```
SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

 The library libVuforia.so could not be loaded
```

According one of the forum post's answer I have edited the XML file and given the absolute path ,

```
<copy overwrite="true" todir="libs/armeabi-v7a">
            <fileset dir="E:\vuforia-sdk-android-3-0-9\build\lib\armeabi-v7a"/>
        </copy>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, i have solve it with this step:

1. in vuforia sdk folder, ...\vuforia sdk android7\build
   you will find 3 folders: include, java and lib
2. create a zip from the “lib” folder
3. rename lib.zip in lib.jar
4. add this jar to bils of your project

I have find this solution [her](http://www.paolomoschini.it/2015/11/30/trying-vuforia-with-android-studio/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to just manually copy libVuforia.so to the destination folder named in script (libs/armeabi-v7a) and delete the whole copy section from script. It helped me.

Comment: Thank you! Will try that and let you know

Comment: So did you found out a working solution to your problem? I am interested because I am stuck on the same problem you were.

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi are you sure that this is the only problem you have with Vuforia? This solution worked perfectly for me and I also verified it on multiple systems.

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi I checked it only on Windows 7, but it's hardly possible that it's Windows version specific problem...